# Issues with Row Skipping and Deleting Every Other Cell in a Column

Tags: excel

Suppose I want to match up one column with every second row of another column. That is A1 goes with B1, A2 goes with B3, A3 goes with B5, and so on. I tried using `IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,B1,"")` but this still results in B2,B4,B6, and so on being skipped. That is, the values that actually show up are only the odd values of B.

Essentially my issue is that I am trying to match up a column with information every other row to a column with information every row. Is there a way to use OFFSET or a similar function to accomplish this task.

Alternatively, is there any easy way to get Excel to recognize the cells that (according to the CODE() function) are blank so that I can use GoTo and delete them, consolidating that column down to one piece of information per row instead of per two rows?

Comment: Do you have key-column so that you can use vlookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Index() to get the data. `=Index(b:b,row()+row()-row($A$1))`.